# custom init for UICollectionViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UICollectionViewCell that is initialized in my nib file inside a collection view.. here's how I am initializing it:

```
PNRCatalogSourceCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

is there a way to do a custom init for this to pass in objects that it will use.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subclass of `PNRCatalogSourceCell` and pass in objects inside `awakeFromNib`
method

Comment: you mean create a custom awakeFromNib?

Comment: by just overriding the method

Comment: How can I call some form of init if I'm not loading the class from a Nib?